# Please solve this riddle

Tags: riddle

Where there are two, you see just one.
But if there are thirty, you will see none.
It comes in a month, but not in a year.
Horror has several, but it causes no fear.
It's in Wisconsin, but not New Hampshire.
It's in a response, but not in an answer.

> HINT: It is not a letter in the alphabet.

Comment: I was going to guess the letter O before seeing the hint... Unless the hint is just saying that the letter O is not in the word "alphabet". Or should I take the hint literally?

Comment: I bet the answer is the letter O and the "hint" is saying that it's not in "alphabet". We've had a similar riddle with the letter E instead asked multiple times, but I suppose this is just different enough not to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Obligatory [xkcd reference](https://xkcd.com/169/)?

Comment: If a 'hint' makes a puzzle harder to solve then it is not a hint.

Answer (score 1):

> The answer is alphabet O. Hint need not be taken literaly ...

Comment: Please explain your answer a little bit more so other users can learn from it and use the spoiler tag >! to hide the answer.

Comment: Why do you believe the hint should not be taken literally, unless you are the same person who posted the question?